# Assetic files not served

Tags: symfony, nginx, assetic

I'm using Symfony 2.5.9, `dev` env, with

```
assetic:
    use_controller: true
```

Trying to use assetic for my resources

```
{% javascripts '@MeMyBundle/Resources/public/js/my-script.js' %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

I'm getting the link generated

```
<script src="/js/60f6e00_my-script_1.js"></script>
```

But NginX complains about it not existing

> 404 Not Found
>   nginx

nginx doesn't even seem to forward the request to SF

---

Here is the config I'm using for nginx

```
root  /data/www/symfony/web;

location / {
    try_files $uri @pass_to_symfony_dev;
}

location ~ /app_dev.php/ {
    try_files $uri @pass_to_symfony_dev;
}

location @pass_to_symfony {
    rewrite ^ /app.php?$request_uri last;
}

location @pass_to_symfony_dev {
    rewrite ^ /app_dev.php?$request_uri last;
}

location ~ ^/app(_dev)?\.php($|/) {
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

I don't know if it's an NginX issue or a SF one.

So the question is: Why NginX sends me a 404 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the rules from http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html#nginx. You are generating urls like `SERVER_NAME/app_dev.php`**?**`REQUEST_URI` instead of `SERVER_NAME/app_dev.php/REQUEST_URI` but your last rule only applies if `app_dev.php` or `app_dev.php/` provided.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, gave up and did the following:

```
{% set serverName = app.request.server.get('SERVER_NAME') %}
{% set serverPort = app.request.server.get('SERVER_PORT') %}
{% set serverAddress = serverName ~ ':' ~ serverPort %}
<link href="http://{{ serverAddress }}/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Coupld probably put protocol in there also, I didnt need to.